# Scrapy splash log-in

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy

I used to use splash form request to login in one of the site. However, developers changed  it, added more javascript, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I added javascript, which beeing used in that site as well.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "lost"
start_urls = ["mysite",]                  ###########changed main loggin form

def start_requests(self):

    for url in self.start_urls:
     yield SplashRequest(
      url, 
      self.parse, 
      args={'wait': 1},
     )

def parse(self, response):
    return SplashFormRequest.from_response(
        response,  
        formdata={'mail': 'mymail', 'pass': 'mypasswd'},
        callback=self.after_login
    )


def after_login(self,response):
    print('This is body '+response.body+' The end of body')
    ### Going to film list ######
    if "Username" in response.body:
        self.logger.error("##Success##")
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="mail"],input[name="pass"]').keydown(function (e)
    {
        if(e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            login();
        }
    });
});
function login()
{
    mail = $('input[name="mail"]').val();
    pass = $('input[name="pass"]').val();
    if($('input[name="rem"]:checked').length)
        rem = 1;
    else
        rem = 0;
    if(mail.length && pass.length > 5)
    {
        metrikaEvents('LOGIN');
        console.log('OK!');
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ajaxik.php",
                    dataType : "json",
                    data: 
                    {
                        act:'users',
                        type:'login',
                        mail:encodeURIComponent(mail),
                        pass:encodeURIComponent(pass),
                        rem:encodeURIComponent(rem)
                     },
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        if(msg.result == 'ok')
                        {
                            if(msg.error)
                            {
                                switch(msg.error)
                                {
                                    default:
                                        text =   lf_config.errors.user.login_error;
                                    break;
                                }
                                ntfctn(text,'error');
                            }
                            else if(msg.success)
                            {
                              ntfctn(msg.name+lf_config.notifications['user_login'],'information');
                                setTimeout('goTo("/",false)',1000);
//                              goTo('/',false);
                            }
                        }
                    },
        });
    }
}
function loginTogglePass(t)
{
    if($('input[name="'+t+'"]').attr('type') == 'password')
    {
        $('input[name="'+t+'"]').attr('type','text');
        $('input[name="'+t+'"]').prev('div.eye-  icon').removeClass('closed').addClass('opened');
    }
    else
    {
        $('input[name="'+t+'"]').attr('type','password');
        $('input[name="'+t+'"]').prev('div.eye-icon').removeClass('opened').addClass('closed');
    }
}
```

I see that javascript looking for "enter" key down. But clicking button should work as well. Can anyone put me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason to use Splash rather than ordinary Scrapy's FormRequest?

Comment: I thought if you using  splash, you should use it SplashFormRequest? Is there major difference between them?

Comment: Actually you can use both Splash and regular Scrapy requests. Moreover SplashRequest is wrapper for Scrapy's Request that under the hood just populates `meta` values in more convenient way.

Comment: One thing to add here is Scrapy does not handle single page applications by default. Splash, however, does, so combining them allows scraping Angular, React, etc sites, which are increasingly common.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Borrowed idea from this topic

[enter Scrapy + splash: can't select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632784/scrapy-splash-cant-select-element/41680002#41680002)

Instead using formdata to login, use splash and detect page's elements one by one

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "lost"
allowed_domains = ["mydomain"]
start_urls = ['myurl']
req = 10
series = {}





def start_requests(self):                               
    script = """
    function main(splash)
        local url = splash.args.url
        assert(splash:go(url))
        assert(splash:wait(10))

        splash:set_viewport_full()

        local search_input = splash:select('input[name=mail]')   
        search_input:send_text("email")
        local search_input = splash:select('input[name=pass]')
        search_input:send_text("password")
        assert(splash:wait(5))
        local submit_button = splash:select('input[class^=primary-btn]')
        submit_button:click()

        assert(splash:wait(10))

        return {
            html = splash:html(),
            png = splash:png(),
        }
      end
    """
    yield SplashRequest(
        'myurl',
        callback = self.after_login,      ###inserting callabck
        endpoint='execute',
        args={
        'lua_source': script,
        'ua': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36"
        }
                        )

def parse(self, response):
    script = response.body
```