# Scrapy Splash - Stay logged

Tags: python, session, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I maneged to connect on a website using scrapy+splash (thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41989252/scrapy-splash-log-in)).

I know I'm logged because I can display some elements that are available once you're logged in. But as soon as I try to reach another page with another `SplashRequest`, the website ask to log again.

So it seems that scrapy (or splash) doesn't keep the session active. Is there something to enable in order to stay logged, and keep the session active ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Splash starts each render from a clean state, so if you want to keep session you need to initialize cookies first, and also make Scrapy aware of cookies set during the render. See [Session Handling](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash#session-handling) section in scrapy-splash README. A complete example could look like this (copy-paste from the README):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

script = """
function main(splash)
  splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)
  assert(splash:go{
    splash.args.url,
    headers=splash.args.headers,
    http_method=splash.args.http_method,
    body=splash.args.body,
    })
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))

  local entries = splash:history()
  local last_response = entries[#entries].response
  return {
    url = splash:url(),
    headers = last_response.headers,
    http_status = last_response.status,
    cookies = splash:get_cookies(),
    html = splash:html(),
  }
end
"""

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):


    # ...
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse_result,
            endpoint='execute',
            cache_args=['lua_source'],
            args={'lua_source': script},
        )

    def parse_result(self, response):
        # here response.body contains result HTML;
        # response.headers are filled with headers from last
        # web page loaded to Splash;
        # cookies from all responses and from JavaScript are collected
        # and put into Set-Cookie response header, so that Scrapy
        # can remember them.
```

Note that sessions currently require using /execute or /run endpoint, there are no helpers for other endpoints.